# Xcode symbol file location

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, symbols

Does Xcode output a symbol file or is it possible to produce one? We're capturing our own crash reports from devices in our own format and would like to symbolise them so we can have a faster turnaround than waiting for Apple to make crash reports available.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ensure that your application is built with debug flags enabled.

The file should be in your library folder:

`~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<weird-app-identifier>/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos`

Inside this folder, there will be a .dSYM bundle folder which contains the symbol file further inside `Contents/Resources/`.

You can also generate a .dSYM bundle file by running `dsymutil` on a binary/library.