# Xcode stuck with "Copying symbol files"

Tags: ios, xcode

After updating to the latest version (6.1 b2), Xcode does not compile and run projects on the device anymore and shows "Copying symbol files" for hours. Any ideas or possible workarounds for this problem?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Try to use another cable or USB port - Other usb port fixed it for me and got the idea while finding this twitter post: [Tweet Gone]

Comment: That's it. I had an USB-extension connected to the iMac. Everything worked fine so far, so I had no idea, this could be the reason. I changed the USB port and plugged in the original USB-jack => symbol copying and processing was done within 3 minutes. Thank you.

Comment: Tweet gone, please quote next time.

Comment: Sorry the tweet was just saying "swapped Lightning cable fixed it"

Comment: This fixed the same prob on Xcode 8.3.2. I figured as this is such a well known, stupid issue that I filed radr://problem/32465352 against it.

Comment: Fixed it for me on XCode15

Comment: Macbook Pro M1 - Just switched the usb port I plugged in the device in it works! Apple!

Answer (score 29):

Try this:

1. Clean Project
2. Option + Product -> Clean Build Folder
3. Remove this folder Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache
4. Find your project folder in Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ and remove
5. Restart Xcode

Comment: Thank you for the really fast reply. I followed the procedure several times in different variations, but XCode is still "copying symbol files". Strange.

Comment: These steps worked for me.  After restarting it took a few minutes to "process symbols" and then I could install and run my app on my phone.  I had just recently updated from iOS 7.x to 8.1.

Comment: Been stuck for hours with a similar problem after remove a pod, I had tried everything expect removing Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache. That solved it. Thanks!

Comment: thank you for an answer that isn't "check the usb cord/port" I know my cord is fine. This did the trick.

Comment: It's funny how it's the same correct answer for a lot of different questions.

Answer (score 26):

I encountered the same problem.
Rebooting my iPhone worked for me.

Comment: I tried the cable solution first - That didn't work.  After rebooting my device once, only then would it let me proceed - Thanks @qfujiwara

Answer (score 6):

I just spent the last several hours troubleshooting this issue on my device.  I am running a virtual version of Mavericks on VBox.  For me, the problem was resolved by installing Oracle VM Virtualbox Extension Pack.  There was a problem with VBox fully recognizing the USB.  It would recognize in iTunes, but not in XCode.  This may be helpful for anyone running XCode on a virtual machine

Comment: what version of Vbox you are using, Xcode ver and ios ver??

Comment: I had the same problem with this steps:
- installed Oracle VM Virtualbox Extension Pack
- set (machine) settings -> USB -> USB 2.0 (turn off the machine to enable the combo)

don't know if the extansion did anything, anyway thanks @Vette so much for the advise!!

Comment: On VirtualBox as well, USB 2.0 didn't work, but USB 3.0 worked for me. You can have a look in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport for your device folder, it should go over 1GB (took about 10 min). Previously it was stuck at 300Kb.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, **"Rebooting Xcode" & ensuring my iPhone was unlocked** did the trick.

It appears that my Symbols file download began previously (as the Symbols directory for iOS 7.1.2 was in the expected location in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/), but did not complete, & thus sometimes was "sticking" and other times completing but showing my iPhone as unavailable.

When I restarted Xcode, I ensured that I already had the iPhone unlocked & then instead of just getting the "Copying symbol files" message, I also got a "Processing symbol files" message, after which my iPhone was available to run the app.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can try just to reboot your device - helps for me.

Answer (score 1):

There are random solutions for this :

1. Please make sure that your `device is unlocked` when you run app.
2. `Reboot your device.`
3. Clean project using `cmd+shift+k.` You can also try Clean Build folder using `alt+shift+cmd+k`.
4. `Delete the content of derived data` and rebuild you app.
5. `Quit Xcode` and re-run your app.

Solution 1 and 2 worked in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the folder:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/<device's iOS version>
```

Then restart the device and restart xcode.

Apparently when the import symbol got stuck half way through it will never finish anymore, deleting the folder above should ensure the process restarts.

Comment: This worked for me, it was probably related to my faulty cable, but without deleting it was never progressing. See also this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28343126/1736679)

Answer (score 0):

By restarting my iPad(iOS device) resolve the issue. 
To cop with exc_bad_access error, I have enabled zombie objects in Xcode from menu -> product -> scheme -> edit scheme -> run -> diagnostics . And after that such issue started. I have disabled it and restart my iPad and eventually it will work.
I hope restarting iOS device will resolve your issue too.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen also because of some usb hubs. Please try to connect your device without a usb hub.

Comment: This is (still even today) completely correct.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading an iPhone to ios17.0.3 i hit this problem. Rebooted my Mac and iPhone and it went away. Xcode connected and ran a debug session within a few seconds (briefly showing "Preparing iPhone......").

Answer (score 0):

Quitting the Xcode worked for me

1. Disconnect your iOS device
2. Quit the Xcode
3. Re-open the Xcode
4. Connect the device
5. It will start copying symbol

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was:

1. Clear the project
2. Disconnect WiFi from Mac
3. Connect the iPhone via USB
4. Click on the iPhone name on the top bar and click on `Manage Run Destinations...`
5. And click on the device on the left, it start the copy process but much faster, in seconds is completed

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

On `an old iPad`, very slow connect via USB, use `connect via network`

1. firstly xcode plug in device + trust device
2. XCode select, Connect via Network
3. reboot device
4. restart XCode, select build to device
5. Xcode resume download symbols over WIFI

All connected up in less than 2 mins. ✅ Success

Answer (score -1):

reinstalling Xcode 7.2 seems to have helped
it has progressed past the "copying symbol files" and
showed a blue progress bar next to expanded "exporting symbol files"
(restarting Xcode and devices did not, replugging power to usb hub did not,
plugging to the mac directly bypassing usb hub did not : it was stuck for good
)